# ¿Crear predicado utilizando operador :-op?

Tags: prolog

Tengo unas dudas respecto al operador :-op en Prolog, debido a que no lo se manejar. Mi ejercicio está enfocada en crear un predicado que a partir de una lista atributo-valor, cuyo formato es [a1=>v1, a2=>v2,...,aN=>vN], obtenga el valor de un atributo que se le pida.

> Ejemplo: ?- valor(forma, [color=>azul, forma=>esferica, peso=>ligero,
>   material=>plastico], X). X=esferica.

Para ello, nos sugieren definir el operador => en la base lógica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La directiva `op/3` te permite declarar átomos que serán tratados sintácticamente como operadores con una determinada clase (infijo, sufijo o prefijo), asociatividad y prioridad.

En tu caso, necesitas un operador `=>/2` infijo que no sea asociativo:

```
:- op(300, xfx, '=>').
```

Ahora puedes manejar el átomo `'=>'(x,y)` como `x => y` (aunque internamente estas dos estructuras son equivalentes).

Finalmente, puedes escribir tu predicado `valor/3` como:

```
valor(X, [X=>Y|_], Y).
valor(X, [_|T], Y) :- valor(X, T, Y).
```

[Aquí](http://www.deransart.fr/prolog/bips.html#operators) tienes más información sobre los operadores en Prolog.

Comment: Gracias Jose, déjeme ver si intento y hago mi predicado y hago consultas. Muchas gracias por las respuestas!

Comment: De nada ;-) Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada para dejar la pregunta resuelta.

Comment: Es así, sin problemas. Gracias por las sugerencias y la ayuda.!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wao, sorprendente. Me funcionó sin problemas. Gracias por la colaboración.

```
?- valor(forma, [color=>azul, forma=>esferica, peso=>ligero, material=>plastico], X). 
X = esferica ; 
false. 

?- valor(peso, [color=>azul, forma=>esferica, peso=>ligero, material=>plastico], X). 
X = ligero ; 
false. 

?- valor(casa, [color=>azul, forma=>esferica, peso=>ligero, material=>plastico], X). 
false.
```